# Where to get custom progress bar like in google android apps?

Tags: android, gmail, progress-bar

In one of google apps I noticed cute round progress bar which animated like two divided parts leafing one to another one. It seems like I saw it some time ago in gmail app but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: great but what is your problem actually?

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know where to get this progress bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this. It can be found on GitHub : [Google Progress Bar](https://github.com/jpardogo/GoogleProgressBar)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is it! Did you use it ? There is a slim whit line in the middle of the circle, don't you know how to hide it ?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't tried it. You can open an issue at the GitHub for your problem.